# Converting Shapefile elevation field to height field

Tags: qgis, dted

Have been trying to update the elevation field in my shapefile (vector file *.shp) into a height field. Have tried to rasterize the shapefile then deduct the height using Raster Calculator with a reference dted (raster map). Then I filled the empty space with nodata. After which I polygonize.

I have managed to get some resemblance of the height but however, I have found that the height in the shapefile is rounded off and the processing process actually cost me to lose some features.

All of this is done in  QGIS 2.2

Is there a better way I can do this?

One of the way I am trying to explore is to use field Calculators in vector shapefile properties. Can I reference an external raster map layer with this? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. It sounds like you have a vector file, with a height attribute and you're wanting to compare this with an elevation raster, right? Let me know if this is what you're asking and I'll try to answer.